# How can I prevent app from hanging on phones with low RAM?

Tags: android

I have developed an app which uses appcompat theme as the main theme.
In some activities there are more than 300 lines of code which use several card views, and in them are spinners and edit texts.

It performs well in many phones, but in phones with low RAM it hangs and causes the memory to be freed

I've used asynctask but the InBackground method is worker and doesn't interfere with graphics.

How can I handle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is really good documentation on this issue on the `Android Developer` website: http://developer.android.com/training/articles/memory.html

Please post code if there is a specific area that you are concerned with.

Comment: Thanks , I've got some Ideas by reading it . I'll test them if worked, I'll post the codes.

Answer (score 0):

When programming to mobile we need to face this kind of challenge. You should specify a target when you start to develop. In other words, it is really hard to develop an app which has the same and perfect behavior in all devices.

Brotip: Try to break your code. Is not usual to have more than 300 line of code in one file. Your method probably can be optimized. Otherwise, there is nothing you can do, once you reach the physical limitation of RAM size you will face this problem.

A solution for this problem COULD be use a Local DB and store the information that you use in this activity. Then you read it little by little.

Hope it helps and give you some ideas.